# How does net inventory value affect further deposity into a fund?

Tags: financial-literacy, annual-report

I am trying to understand finances regarding funds and yearly calculation of net inventory value (NIV).

Say I've deposited $50,000 into a fund. Next year I get an annual report that says: the net inventory value has dropped to 0.5 per share  (due to valuation of assets, j-curve, etc) for the previous year, 2023.

So now the value of my shares of this fund are $25,000 while I paid $50,000 for them. This is the part I understand.

What I fail to understand: Starting 2024 I add another $10,000 to this fund.
Total sum paid: $60,000

But what is my current value of my shares? The NIV for 2024 has not been calculated yet, but the additional $10,000 also have probably not been invested into something and theoretically should be at a NIV of 1.0?

Do I calculate my NIV of my shares by `$50,000 * 0.5 + $10,000 * 1.0` or do I now assume that the new shares do also drop in 'value' until I get the next annual report (which would be (`$50,000 * 0.5 + $10,000 * 0.5`)?

Edit for clarification: This is not an exchange traded fund that gets it's share price from the exchange. One share has a fixed initial price, whose price does not change (but the value might)

Comment: *One share has a fixed initial price, whose price does not change (but the value might)* - never heard of such a thing, can you provide an example?

Comment: @littleadv actually they are very common, but often unknown to most exchange focussed people. See https://www.ici.org/cef/background/bro_g2_ce#FeaturesClosed-EndFunds . Closed-End Funds have a fixed amount of shares and a period where they gather new money (AFAIK 'placement phase'), since this phase can take years and meanwhile the fond can invest or simply incur costs through management, a share's worth can change (NIV) but the fund may still emit shares at the price of the beginning of the placement phase.

Comment: @littleadv another very common type is stock of a non-exchange traded company. Such company decides on the price per share and their annual report contains the actual value of the company. If you want (and can) buy more shares of this company, their price is dictated by the issuer, regardless of the company's value. This is also very different to exchanges, because there is no real-time market (which is often not wanted) and a share's price is not influenced by outside factory like emotions or frenzies at the exchanges. ( I am not sure, whether this is called "over the counter (OTC)" trading)

Comment: OTC trading is market trading, and the OTC prices are dictated by supply and demand, independently of the issuer. Companies may sell shares at fixed prices, but unless these are holding companies, there's no NIV for them per se, at least not in a sense you've described. For holding companies (e.g.: closed-end funds) this may potentially occur, but I wonder - is this a real situation or your homework in accounting?

Comment: @littleadv then OTC was the wrong term for that. Sorry for that, the entire setting is in a different language and I translated it into english. This is a real (actually multiple) investments and no homework. I track our finances and was wondering how I could track such investments, that report a NIV while I can still invest into them for the original price. This would be easy, if the NIV resulted in a changed price per share and I would by more or fewer shares with the same money, but this is not something like an ETF instalment plan.

Comment: then the real question is what you want to track. The term "value" is not well defined, but is usually understood to be the amount of money you can get for your investment at your point of inspection. So your value is how much you can sell/redeem it for. You're describing something that you can't sell on the secondary market, and you can't redeem, so it's value would be nil regardless of the NIV.

Comment: @littleadv I agree with you on that. I was curious to calculate the net-worth of my current investments. I find the point-in-time evaluation of illiquid assets also very vague. This is true for holding shares in non-publicly traded stock. I may have bought $1 mio in shares (= the price), but I can define my net worth (= the value) based on whatever I wish by reading fundamental metrics from the annual reports and forming a claim, of what I think my shares are worth now. My initial question is about whether there are hints on how to handle two different time frames of evaluating the worth.

Comment: That would be an accounting question, which is off topic. There's are GAAP and IFRS which provide guidance